# using css's width instead of element's width neutralizes float: left

Tags: html, css

I've a bunch of images which are placed next to each other, to serve as a slider content, so called sprites I believe. Images are forced next to eachother by float: left. This works all fine when I do

```
<img src=".." width="200px" height="160px".
```

However when I put the width and height inside the style attribute:

```
style="{width:239px; height:160px;}"
```

The images outside the screen are put below each other.
The float: left is specified in a separate style sheet. I would really like to use the style way, and I'm a kind of curious why the float left is canceled.

Comment: Is it intentional that your first and second examples have different widths? (200px vs 239px?) Any chance that's related?

Comment: the differences in width was unintentional. Removal of curly brackets did do the trick. Thanks for all the answers. I tend to award the least ranked with equal valued answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
style="width:239px; height:160px;"
```

Remove curly brackets (braces) `{}`

Answer (score 3):

If it works with your first code snippet, it should work with this:

```
<img src=".." style="width:239px; height:160px;" />
```

Note that I removed your curly brackets.

In any case, I'm not sure where the "float neutralization" was coming from.

Even with the curly brackets, it's still floated in this demo in IE7/IE8 + Firefox/Chrome/Safari/Opera:

http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/8S9gM/

As pointed out various other times in this question, make sure you're specifying the correct `width`.

Answer (score 3):

```
style="{width:239px; height:160px;}"
```

This is invalid HTML. You don't use curly brackets within inline `style=` declarations, so this should work:

```
style="width:239px; height:160px;"
```

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't use inline styles, it is a bad practice, put all your rules in the external style sheet.

It is easier to maintain and allows you to update groups of items more quickly.

Also, the `width` attribute on the inline style is `239px` not `200px` and remove the curly braces.

As long as you have specified the class correctly there should be no reason for the `float` to have been cancelled.